# Reference function in Makefile?

Tags: make

I'm modifying a `Makefile` to add a command which will be used to update and compile a dependency.

I already have the `make clean` command working. Now I'm trying to make it run before I run any other `make` command.

I'm trying by adding `all: clean` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.PHONY: all
all: clean

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf build

update-dep:
        mkdir -p build/package_name \
          && # do stuff here
```

How can I run clean when any of the other functions is run?

Comment: _"I'm trying to make `make clean` run before I run any other make command."_ -- **Why** would you want to do that?

Comment: @ilkkachu is it a bad idea? I'm new to `make`, really I just want to run clean before I run `update-dep`.

Comment: The point of Make is that it only does the work that is needed to update everything, instead of doing everything, everytime. Removing all compiled files as the first thing works exactly against that idea...

Comment: @ilkkachu that makes sense, so in my actual program I will probably just clean the dependency that I'm updating. That said knowing the syntax for referencing one command from inside another or from all will be useful.

Comment: If you’re worried about processing dependencies, and considering cleaning stuff, that probably means your Makefile isn’t specific enough. Handling dependencies is `make`’s *job*; your job when you use it is to describe all the dependencies between files you manipulate. Once your dependencies are fully described, `make` takes care of everything itself. (Of course that “fully described” part can be hard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you know how dependencies work, you just stick them after the colon. 
So a somewhat common idiom would be to have a dependency `all` like this:

```
all: main_program
```

It's only special in that the *first* target in the file is the default target, so an explicit `all` at the start of the Makefile allows you to set the default.

With `main_program` depending on `main_program.o` etc. If you want to add `clean` there as a dependency, just list it along the others:

```
all: clean main_program

update_dep: clean
    do stuff...
```

Listing `all: clean` with no other dependencies would make `make all` the same as `make clean`, so you probably want to add some other dependency there.

It's still not a very good idea to clean up everything before every run, since the whole idea of Make is that it figures out which files need to be updated, and only does the work required for that. You need to explicitly stick `clean` as a dependency of all other targets if you want it to run every time.